# $(element).focus() not working as expected in callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm writing an HTML form for use in a kind of informal lending library.  I've made radio buttons to determine whether a person is leaving or taking a book.  When the buttons are clicked, I'd like to show one form and hide another.  I have that functionality basically working, but I'm having trouble placing focus on the first text input in the form when the radio button is selected.  Here's my example:

```
 $("#addRadio").click(function(){
    $("#takeForm").slideUp();
    $("#addForm").slideDown(400, function(){
        $("#addSearchField").focus(); 
        console.log("This fired")});
    })
```

When `#addRadio` is clicked, the sliding up/down happens fine, and the `console.log` fires, but `#addSearchField` doesn't get focus.  If a user starts typing, a little focus box appears around the `addRadio` button, which was the last element they would have clicked.

What am I missing?

Comment: Please create a codepen to demonstrate your code example

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/htoL2gwk/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.  I had a "name" attribute but not an "id" attribute for the form field I was trying to focus on.  I'm surprised nothing showed up in the console for that.